# While Loop and if statement

Tags: python

Edited to be clear on what I want

I want a random 7 to 14 characters long string, which contains the letters 'd' to 'g', with no consecutive repeated letters. 
Example of expected output: `dgfede`

```
import random

num = random.randint(7,14)
print(num)

message=""
end = False 
for n in range(num):

    while end == False:
        newnum= random.randint(100,103)           
        val=chr(newnum)
        val = newnum
        message +=chr(val)


        if(message != message[-1:]):
            print(message)
            end=True
        else:
            message =""
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? You currently have an infinite loop. The if condition is never satisfied, as message is one letter and so is message[-1], therefore you always turn message into an empty string and redo everything. Also, you make two consecutive assignments to "val".

Comment: The code is suppose to repeat itself until it outputs something like efdedeg which is the length of what num generated

Comment: You should explain the **exact** functionality you want the code to have for people to help you. If I have to guess, you want a random 7 to 14 characters long string, which contains the letters 'd' to 'g', with no consecutive repeated letters. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is what I want the program to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
import random

num = random.randint(7, 14)
print num

message = ""
prevnum = -1
for n in range(num):
    newnum = random.randint(100, 103)
    while newnum == prevnum:
        newnum = random.randint(100, 103)
    prevnum = newnum
    message += chr(newnum)
```

You have made numerous mistakes in your code, you should review them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `choice` in combination with `replace`:

```
import random
num = random.randint(7, 14)
chars = "defg"
result = ""
for n in range(num):
    result += random.choice(chars.replace(result[-1:],''))
```